# How can I resolve nestjs class-validator

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

The nestjs class-validator does not work.
For example, if I send a post request with a number for LoginId, I get a normal response.

```
import { IsNumber, IsString } from 'class-validator';

export class LoginUserDto {
  @IsString()
  loginId: string;

  @IsString()
  password: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class-validator needs to work with Pipe.

You can refer to the following code to inject APP_PIPE or see the [nestjs/pipe](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes) doc.

```
import { Module, ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_PIPE } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    {
      provide: APP_PIPE,
      useValue: new ValidationPipe({
        whitelist: true,
      }),
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Class Validator should work I am Using it for a long time.

I think in your case it treats LoginId(number, your input) as a string
Try Class Transformer

```js
import { IsNumber, IsString, IsNotEmpty() } from 'class-validator';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';

export class LoginUserDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @Type(()=>String)
  loginId: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  password: string;
}
```